# Cannot start elastic search in my project on Windows

Tags: elasticsearch, environment-variables, mongoosastic

I've installed elastic search on Windows 10 but I have a problem. I included JAVA_HOME and C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45 in my environment variables under systems variables. Everything works fine when I'm running elasticsearch on

```
    C:\Users\elasticsearch-2.3.2\bin
```

But when I try to start elasticsearch in my project I get an error like this:

```
    sh.exe":elasticsearch: command not found
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: How do you run it in your project?

Comment: I just type the command: "elasticsearch" and I get that error.

Comment: Where did you type? You may need to add elasticsearch bin folder to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it to work!